# Writing to multiple PhD advisors in same group: a separate email?

Tags: phd, advisor, email

I have contacted two potential PhD advisors in the same group, informing them that I also contacted the other one. They replied separately, one put the other in CC and the other mentioned having aligned with the first in his reply.

To e.g., ask for clarifications or a meeting, can I send a single email with them as recipients, or should I send the same email separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, once people start CCing others in an email chain, they want them to be involved in further communications. So with both advisors being in the same group, and them having actively started to include each other when talking to you, I suggest you just email them both.